# templateUrl does not work

Tags: node.js, angular, materialize

I'm trying to make [angular2-material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize) app

It works when I `template: ~` but If I use `templateUrl: ~`, `<my-app>` contains nothing even `Loading...` and a Network log Informed me the template successfully loaded `200 GET /app/mainLayout.html`

Basically, I followed [quick start guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) of angular2 docs and these are what I did

1. installing angular2-materialize by npm
2. `import "angular2-materialize"` in `main.ts`
3. add System.config in index.html

index.html

```
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  packages: {
    "materialize-css": {
      "main": "dist/js/materialize"
    },
    "materialize": {
      "main": "dist/materialize-directive",
      "defaultExtension": "js"
    }
  },
  map: {
    "materialize-css": "node-modules/materialize-css",
    "materialize": "node_modules/angular2-materialize",
    "angular2-materialize": "node_modules/angular2-materialize"
  }
});
System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

4. add MaterializeDirective in app.component.ts

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterializeDirective } from 'angular2-materialize';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [MaterializeDirective],
  templateUrl: 'app/views/mainLayout.html',
  styleUrls: ['/app/css/mainLayout.css']
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

This is my working dir

```
|
|-app
|  |-css
|  |  |-mainLayout.css
|  |-views
|  |  |-mainLayout.html
|  |
|  |-app.component.ts
|  |-main.ts
|
|-node_modules
|  |-(....)
|-typings
|  |-globals
|  |  |-(...)
|  |-index.d.ts
|-package.json
|-systemjs.config.js
|-tsconfig.json
|-typings.json
```

one more thing. I think --regardless of `template:` statement-- it seems some path are setted wrong. *.js files are loaded successfully but *.map files are not.

```
[1] 16.06.21 20:17:15 200 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js
[1] 16.06.21 20:17:15 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/Subject.js.map
```

like this

Comment: Is there any error thrown?

Comment: @HerringtonDarkholme added network logs

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [MaterializeDirective],
  templateUrl: './app/views/mainLayout.html',
  styleUrls: ['/app/css/mainLayout.css']
})
```

The key difference being `'./app/`. This makes Angular look for the "mainLayout.html" in the current root `/app/views/`.

Comment: I think it is absolute path. See also http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html

Comment: ./app/~, /app/~, app/~ all same as before.

Comment: Alright, could you try to set up a Plnkr to tinker with?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know what happend, I resolved the problem somehow. Few more restarting npm and `app/views/mainLayout.html` were solution. but the angular2 still find .map in wrong path. Please let me know why it happen if there are someone who have a idea.